# Udev - How to change device group?

Tags: usb, permissions, udev, devices

By default, all hard drive and usb drive devices belong to group "disk". I want to change usb drives to group "adm".

I verified the ID_BUS

```
$ udevadm info -q all -n /dev/sdb | grep ID_BUS
E: ID_BUS=usb
```

I created the file /etc/udev/rules.d/70-persistent-usb.rules and insert the following

```
# Enable admin controls on all usb devices.
ID_BUS=="usb", GROUP="adm"
```

Lastly, I disconnected my usb drive and reconnected it. It is still showing

```
$ ll /dev/sdb
brw-rw---- 1 root disk 8, 16 Apr 14 19:31 /dev/sdb
```

The drive group is not "adm"? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the `udevadm info` output, you see the `E` prefix which is used for environment variables. You can match against it with:

```
ENV{ID_BUS}=="..."
```

If you are trying to make just USB devices writable, see this recent question on Unix.SE:

- [Writing raw images safely to USB sticks](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/124540/8250)

Answer (score 0):

You made a mistake by using `ID_BUS` to write your udev rule, in that case it's just `BUS`, try with this one instead:

```
# Enable admin controls on all usb devices.
BUS=="usb", GROUP="adm"
```